# LS_COLORS colors using putty

Tags: bash, putty, colors

I am using putty as a terminal emulator to connect to a remote machine running a bash shell. In putty I have altered the colors displayed (roughly matching the solarized theme). When I log in, the background and text reflect my putty color settings, and if I open a file for editing in vim with syntax highlighting enabled, it uses the colors set in putty. However, using the `ls` command, the colors are still the original default colors. How do I get `ls` to use the colors specified in putty?

Comment: Hello, does anything here help? https://serverfault.com/questions/463784/changing-colors-of-files-dirs-in-linux-ls

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The problem is that `ls` doesn't respect or overrides the color settings in putty, so changes in the putty settings don't affect `ls`. I tried changing xterm color definitions, but that also had no effect.